# Background Data to Content Page Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, background-service

I have a problem I have a Background Service where I read data from Sensors (Android). Now I need the data from the Sensor at a ContenPage in PLC
but I dont know how can I send the data to PLC

```
` public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent,     StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    az = new Azimut();
    sd = new StepDetector(obererSchwellenWert, untererSchwellenWert, timerFlag, false);
     //Start der Sensoren
    Task.Run(() =>
    {


        var mSensorManager = (SensorManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);
        var mLinearAccelerometer = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.LinearAcceleration);
        mSensorManager.RegisterListener(sd, (Sensor)mLinearAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Fastest);
        var mAzimutMagneticField = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
        mSensorManager.RegisterListener(az, (Sensor)mAzimutMagneticField, SensorDelay.Normal);
        var mAzimutAccelerometer = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);
        mSensorManager.RegisterListener(az, (Sensor)mAzimutAccelerometer, SensorDelay.Normal);
    });

    //Listener für Schritte
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
 //I need this Data
            if (sd.schritt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i+++": "+az.azimut);

                sd.schritt = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}`
```

this is my Background Service

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessagingCenter. Which allows communication between 2 different components/objects, which may not have a reference to other.

Your ContentPage or App class will subscribe to messgingcenter and you will send message to messagingcenter from BackgroundService. Basically you can use.

Below article explains backgrounding in Xamarin Forms article in more details. Hope this helps.

http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/